# Python send email with "quoted-printable" transfer-encoding and "utf-8" content-encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtp

python's `email.mime` tends to use encoding `base64` or `7bit` and `us-ascii`.  I would like to use `quoted-printable` and `utf-8` as this is easier for humans to read and debug.

Currently, my emails look like

```
--===============6135350048414329636==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKCmZvciBpIGluIHs4Mjg4Li44N
```

or

```
--===============0756888342500148236==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

happy face =E2=98=BA
```

I would like the raw email to be in quoted-printable unicode so it is easier for humans to read.

```
--===============5610730199728027971==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

happy face ☺
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode MIMEText as quoted printables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939018/encode-mimetext-as-quoted-printables)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403265/how-do-i-use-python-3-2-email-module-to-send-unicode-messages-encoded-in-utf-8-w

Comment: For Python 3.6+ see also now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039715/python3-email-message-to-disable-base64-and-remove-mime-version/66041936#66041936

Answer (score 13):

### short answer

#### set `content-transfer-encoding`

When creating the `MIMEText` object, which will be attached to the `MIMEMultipart` object, set the `content-transfer-encoding` to value `quoted-printable` first, then do `set_payload`. The order of operations matters.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# first create MIMEText, then set content-transfer-encoding, then set payload
mt = MIMEText(None, _subtype='plain')
mt.replace_header('content-transfer-encoding', 'quoted-printable')
mt.set_payload(u'happy face ☺', 'utf-8')

# create the parent email object and the MIMEMultipart extension to it
email = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
inline = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

# assemble the objects
inline.attach(mt)
email.attach(inline)
```

#### set email `charset` and various encodings

```
cs = charset.Charset('utf-8')
cs.header_encoding = charset.QP
cs.body_encoding = charset.QP
email.set_charset(cs)
```

#### Result

This creates a raw email that is human readable (except the base64 encoded file attachment)

```
>>> print(email)
--===============5610730199728027971==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

happy face ☺

--===============5610730199728027971==--

--===============0985725891393820576==
Content-Type: text/x-sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.sh"

Zm9vYmFyc2RmYXNkZmtqaGFzZGZrbGhhc2ZrbGpoYXNma2xqaGFzZmtsaGZkYXNmCg==

--===============0985725891393820576==--
```

---

### long answer

The following is a longer script to provide more context for the prior code snippets.

This script will send a `text/plain` section encoded in UTF-8.  For fun, it will also attach a file.
The raw email this produces will be human readable (except for the file attachment).

```
from __future__ import print_function

from email import charset    
from email.encoders import encode_base64
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes

# create the parent email object
email = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
# set email charset and email encodings
cs_ = charset.Charset('utf-8')
cs_.header_encoding = charset.QP
cs_.body_encoding = charset.QP
email.set_charset(cs_)

# create the 'text/plain' MIMEText
# first create MIMEText, then set content-transfer-encoding, then set payload
mt = MIMEText(None, _subtype='plain')
mt.replace_header('content-transfer-encoding', 'quoted-printable')
mt.set_payload(u'happy face ☺', 'utf-8')

# assemble the parts
inline = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
inline.attach(mt)
email.attach(inline)

# for fun, attach a file to the email
my_file = '/tmp/test.sh'
mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(my_file)
mimetype = mimetype or 'application/octet-stream'
mimetype = mimetype.split('/', 1)
attachment = MIMEBase(mimetype[0], mimetype[1])
attachment.set_payload(open(my_file, 'rb').read())
encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(my_file))
email.attach(attachment)
```

#### Result

This creates a raw email that is human readable (except the base64 encoded file attachment)

```
>>> print(email)
--===============5610730199728027971==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

happy face ☺

--===============5610730199728027971==--

--===============0985725891393820576==
Content-Type: text/x-sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.sh"

Zm9vYmFyc2RmYXNkZmtqaGFzZGZrbGhhc2ZrbGpoYXNma2xqaGFzZmtsaGZkYXNmCg==

--===============0985725891393820576==--
```

---

#### (bonus) send the email

Using `smtplib`, the email can be emailed.

```
import smtplib

# set email address headers
email['From'] = 'me@email.com'
email['To'] = 'you@email.com'
email['Subject'] = 'hello'

# send the email
smtp_srv = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
smtp_srv.set_debuglevel(True)
print(mesg_html, end='\n\n')
print(email.as_string(), end='\n\n')
smtp_srv.sendmail('me@email.com', 'you@email.com', email.as_string())
smtp_srv.quit()
```

Comment: The example doesn't seem to have quoted-printable encoding at all.  Proper QP would look like `happy face =E2=98=BA` -- or, with the nasty overzealous encoding of spaces in Python's default QP implementation, `happy=20face=20=E2=98=BA`.

Comment: You can get the latter with `mt.set_payload(u'happy face ☺'.encode('quoted-printable'), 'utf-8')` I guess.

Comment: Also you should have `_subtype='plain'` not `text/plain` (the `text` is already implied, and not part of the subtype).

Comment: "*The example doesn't seem to have quoted-printable encoding at all*"  Thanks @tripleee , I will review and correct within the next week.  I have corrected the `_subtype`.

Comment: That's not really necessary.  Take the code from one of the linked proposed duplicates instead.

Answer (score 3):

In trying to alter the body of an existing message (email.Message object) and set its encoding to `quoted-printable`, I found that this problem took way more effort than I had anticipated.

```
import email
#... 'part' is the Message object
content = part.get_payload(decode=True)
#... Modify content
part['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = '8bit'
part.set_payload(content, 'UTF-8')
del part['Content-Transfer-Encoding']
email.encoders.encode_quopri(part)
```

Now, why do I set and then delete the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header? The `set_payload` call will set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header and encode the data (to Base64) if no header exists. Otherwise, the `set_payload` call will assume the caller has already encoded the data and will not alter it (by encoding). So, it actually doesn't matter the value to which I set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header, only that I don't leave it blank.

But then why do I need to delete the header? The `email.encoders.encode_quopri` call will only add a header, so the message will result with multiple `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers.

So, just using `set_payload` then `encode_quopri` for a message with no `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header will result in a quoted-printable representation of a Base64 string, and for a message with an existing `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header will result in a message with duplicate headers. Using `encode_quopri` then `set_payload` may result in duplicate headers, but will not encode the message. Hence the add/delete rigamarole to avoid dipping into [the `quopri` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html).

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is just:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import charset

cs = charset.Charset('utf-8')
cs.body_encoding = charset.QP
message = MIMEText(your_body_here, 'plain', cs)
```