# python3 email message to disable base64 and remove MIME-Version

Tags: python, email, utf-8

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
msg = EmailMessage()

msg['From'] = Address("Pepé Le Pew", "pepe", "example.com")
msg['To'] = (
        Address("Penelope Pussycat", "penelope", "example.com")
        , Address("Fabrette Pussycat", "fabrette", "example.com")
        )
msg['Subject'] = 'This email sent from Python code'
msg.set_content("""\
        Salut!

        Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

        [1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

        --Pepé
        """)
print(msg)
```

The above code produces an email message that uses base64 encoding. How to disable it? How to remove the field of MIME-Version?

Will the encoding of "Pepé" be correctly interpreted by the recipient? If not, what is the correct way to ensure its encoding is interpreted by the recipient correctly?

```
From: Pepé Le Pew <pepe@example.com>
To: Penelope Pussycat <penelope@example.com>,
 Fabrette Pussycat <fabrette@example.com>
Subject: This email sent from Python code
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0

CQlTYWx1dCEKCgkJQ2VsYSByZXNzZW1ibGUgw6AgdW4gZXhjZWxsZW50IHJlY2lwaWVbMV0gZMOp
amV1bmVyLgoKCQlbMV0gaHR0cDovL3d3dy55dW1tbHkuY29tL3JlY2lwZS9Sb2FzdGVkLUFzcGFy
YWd1cy1FcGljdXJpb3VzLTIwMzcxOAoKCQktLVBlcMOpCgkJCg==
```

Comment: +1 for including a proper [mre] but only hesitantly because removing the MIME header is completely wrong.

Comment: Similar to [Python send email with "quoted-printable" transfer-encoding and "utf-8" content-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31714221/471376)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely **must not remove** the `MIME-Version:` header; it's what identifies this as a MIME message.

The `From:` header should indeed be RFC2047-encoded, and the documentation suggests that it will be "when the message is serialized". When you `print(msg)` you are not properly serializing it; you want `print(msg.as_string())` which does exhibit the required serialization.

When it comes to the transfer encoding, Python's `email` library has an unattractive penchant for using `base64` for content which could very well be encoded as quoted-printable instead.  You can't really reliably send the content completely unencoded (though if you wanted to, the MIME `8bit` or `binary` encodings would be able to accommodate that; but for backwards compatibility, SMTP requires everything to be encoded into a 7-bit representation).

In the old `email` library, various shenanigans were required to do this, but in the new `EmailMessage` API introduced in Python 3.6, you really only have to add `cte='quoted-printable'` to the `set_content` call.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address

msg = EmailMessage()

msg['From'] = Address("Pepé Le Pew", "pepe", "example.com")
msg['To'] = (
        Address("Penelope Pussycat", "penelope", "example.com")
        , Address("Fabrette Pussycat", "fabrette", "example.com")
        )
msg['Subject'] = 'This email sent from Python code'
msg.set_content("""\
        Salut!

        Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

        [1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

        --Pepé
        """, cte="quoted-printable")   # <-- notice added parameter
print(msg.as_string())                 # <-- properly serialize
```

Unfortunately, figuring this out from the documentation is next to impossible. [The documentation for `set_content`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.set_content) basically just defers to the [`policy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#module-email.policy) which obscurely points to the [`raw_data_manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.raw_data_manager) (if you even notice the link) ... where finally you hopefully notice the presence of the `cte` keyword argument.

Demo: https://ideone.com/eLAt11

(As an aside, you might also want to

```py
replace('\n   ', '\n')
```

in the body text.)

If you go for an `8bit` or `binary` content transfer encoding, the difference between them is that the former has a line length limit (max 900-something characters) whereas the latter is completely unconstrained.  But you need to be sure that the entire SMTP transfer path is 8-bit clean (at which point you might as well pivot to [Unicode email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email) / ESMTP `SMTPUTF8` entirely).

For your possible entertainment, here are some old questions with [crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714221/how-to-send-an-email-with-quoted-printable-transfer-encoding-and-utf-8-content-e) [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939018/encode-mimetext-as-quoted-printables) [for Python 3.5 and earlier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403265/how-do-i-use-python-3-2-email-module-to-send-unicode-messages-encoded-in-utf-8-w)

Comment: What *is* a bug is that Python [creates a `Mime-Version:` header in each _body_ part.](https://bugs.python.org/issue25235) That's something you would usefully want to be able to prevent or remove.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME says "We did not adequately specify how to handle a future MIME version." In this case, why specify it at all? Removing it should work just fine in all practical situations?

Comment: No, there are ambiguities as to what the semantics of some of the other headers are if the `MIME-Version:` header is not present. Its value is unimportant (it should basically always be `1.0`) but it needs to be there.